# change custom seekbars colour in java

Tags: java, android, seekbar

since no one can answer this question [how to enable and disable a seekbar when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377471/how-to-enable-and-disable-a-seekbar-when-clicked?noredirect=1#comment30424256_20377471)

can someone suggest to me how I would change a custom seekbars colour in the java part of my application as I am trying to give an illusion to the user that the seekbar is disabled?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452083/android-seekbar-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-full-seekbar-on-progress/20452370#20452370

Comment: You probabyl should ask your questions only once. I gave an answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467968/using-2-seekbars-in-the-same-activity/20468370#20468370

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this tutorial:
http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/